# How to make TypeScript type guard have an effect on compilation?

Tags: typescript, types

I created a class called `KVMap` which inherits from `Map`, but with whole different types.

```
class KVMap<T extends object> extends Map<keyof T, T[keyof T]> {
    ...
```

Normally `Map`s are used between only two types, like `Record`, yet objects have known key to type associations, so I implemented just that, yet in a `Map`.
Example:

```
type T = {
    a: number,
    b: bigint,
    c: string
};

// becomes

type T = {
    get(key: "a"): number | undefined,
    set(key: "a", value: number): T,

    get(key: "b"): bigint | undefined,
    set(key: "b", value: bigint): T,

    get(key: "c"): string | undefined,
    set(key: "c", value: string): T,
};
```

All types are optionally `undefined` as one can call `.clear` or `.delete` on the keys.

So far everything works fine.

There was one problem with the original type for `Map`: calling `.has` meant that you could still get compiler errors.
Example:

```
if ( map.has(foo) ) {
    map.get(foo)() // error: object may be undefined
}
```

This is due to `.has` simply returning a boolean.
I sought to fix that.

I redefined `.has` in my inherited class as the following:

```
has<K extends keyof T>(key: K): this is this & {
    get(key: K): T[K]
};
```

This should mean that calling `.get` afterward would no-longer have `| undefined` in its type.

Yet I think that the original type of `this`, since it contains the optional undefined, is taking precedence over the type guard union.

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

(I could attach more code, should it be necessary)

Comment: What "assertion" are you talking about?  I don't see any type assertions here

Comment: @jcalz You're right, updating to say "Type Guard" in place of assertion; I had forgotten the name of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from the handbook documentation, but when you create an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) of two callable types, the type it produces acts like an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) with two call signatures, *in the same order as they appear in the intersection*. And so while intuitively [intersections should be *commutative*](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_is_Commutative) and in TypeScript they usually are, intersections of function types are *not*:

```
type FN = {foo(): number};
type FS = {foo(): string};

declare const ns: FN & FS;
ns.foo().toFixed(); // okay
ns.foo().toUpperCase(); // error 

declare const sn: FS & FN;
sn.foo().toFixed(); // error
sn.foo().toUpperCase(); // okay
```

`ns.foo()` returns a `number`, while `sn.foo()` returns a `string`, because in both cases the first call signature hides the second call signature.

---

So the problem with your type guard `this is this & { get(key: K): T[K] }` is that the original `this` had a `get()` method of type `Map<keyof T, T[keyof T]>["get"]`, and so the resulting intersection just adds a new overloaded method *after* that.  Since the original `get()` method works for all `keyof T` inputs, it will always be selected, and so the overloaded method you added is completely hidden:

```
  interface Tee {
    a: string,
    b: number,
    c: boolean
  }

  const v = new KVMap<Tee>();

  if (v.has("a")) {
    v.get; /* OVERLOADED:
    get(key: "a" | "b" | "c"): string | number | boolean | undefined;
    get(key: "a"): string
    */

    v.get("a").toUpperCase(); // error!
```

---

Probably the easiest way to deal with this is to change the order of your intersection so that `this` is last.  So every time you guard with `has()`, a `true` result should add the new `get()` call signature to the *beginning* of the overload list, and thus it should take precedence:

```
  class KVMap<T extends object> extends Map<keyof T, T[keyof T]> {
    declare readonly has: <K extends keyof T>(key: K) => this is {
      get(key: K): T[K]
    } & this;
  }

  const v = new KVMap<Tee>();
  if (v.has("a")) {
    v.get("a").toUpperCase(); // okay now
  }
```

Hooray.

---

Please note, though, that such a type guard only makes sense if you are passing values of a single string literal type to `has()`.  If the parameter to `has()` is of a union type, you will have a bad time, and you could still end up with `undefined` at runtime despite the compiler's assurances to the developer that it's not possible:

```
  // problem
  const bc = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "b" : "c";
  const cb = (bc === "b") ? "c" : "b";
  if (v.has(bc)) {
    v.get(cb).toString(); // compiles fine, but error at runtime!
  }
```

So be careful.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgclAvFA3lAZge0wCgJQBcUAdgK4C2ARhAE5QC+A3ALABQoksAykqhtviIBnYDQCWxAOYMWrNgBMIAYwA2AQxrQlmYiJJCi8KADJus3QDosuPBeCYYYgB4R5+RlAD0nqJgDWaiBsltb4dpgAqmCQNADCakIQ7l4+tDSYdGwKyuqaUNq6wFBCxIY8pvCyJVYCtvaOLm54Ht5QaRls1aF1kdG08YnJrf6BWazEauQQQmBqStAAQmryqGNQ+epCQlAA0gBqALJqYAA8ACptTsAQxPLbmJQAVsrAAHyX17fbR6d+ECCYdBQM4AGmBAG0-gCgWcALrvFBsdbrRSqDTQTTLHQqEBQAAWCSIJx2HxudygUMBwNeOChRB2eCQ72AeLE2zZUBZHNMiNYyORkggwFp-3phAhO1hSOR9GlsrkfKgEmuNHQc2gZwg0F5-LUwlEEkkIOl60oRDIVFoxsV6yUREo2BUEDUxDla3yOj0ADdeMQIAB3XaHY7nLU05rusRAnBeiwEoQ4ABEakTeEZOuRscFwBaACoTVBsyKQERk4moAAfKCJyjlquJpSp-XiKSVkgUah0KsOzBOl1t0i3CDoCSuWT8ot06sp8UiFuSAu5zzu9ZZoVJmfhKIxAZJZopNo0dI0ACEbtY8uCk2ms3mUAA8gFcbzpWitkGfudSV9fE8Xu8ICuMlvhDSkYTBM5IX+Kk4QRAtUVyDFnXkbFcXjIkSUAz5yTA6lizFJlOVZdltgzCd1ynBkiEgyUC3oEwiLZccGEjYgVTVO9NW1As9WKA0pGtfkzXbS0aEE5E7SgHs+1dRVL0VApvV9AMPxDLjw2YqMoBjOMEg3VN0wLNdhTLHpt36BI92Y+T1laMB0koJ1yFfT0ikoJReCOFkLBoF0UPIfAoBOKAAAYLAAVigAB+ataygUtG2YxSiiUSheBwdykEQZAa1TaLq0beLYsTTTo1jeMMqUNNVhtKBjJwVKei4fjJCGVIjwyKA1CKGhB2AMQpjPOSxnoIA)

Comment: I'm dying, TS is a funny language. Since when does order matter in any other language!? Swapped order, worked just fine. Thank you for pointing that out.